# How to batch-process attribute tables in QGIS (or GRASS)?

Tags: qgis, vector, attribute-table, batch, grass.script

I'm using GRASS 6.4.3 in Linuxmint 16.
  I have a bash script for GRASS which I use to process almost 300 raster files.
The script first imports some raster files (`r.in.gdal`), then does some calculations and classification (using `r.mapcalc` and `r.reclass`). And finally transforms the resultant raster to vector (`r.to.vect`) and saves it (`v.out.ogr`, using `type=area`).

Let's say each vector files has a field labeled *category* and that it takes only two values 1 and 2.
As I'm interested only in the total area of polygons with *category = 2* and with an area higher than 10,000 m2, I open each vector file in QGIS, edit its attribute table, calculate the area of each polygon and eliminate all of them with *category=1* and *$area<10,000*.

But I have to do it manually,

Is there a way to do it in a batch process within QGIS?

Or even better, is it possible to do it in GRASS?

Is it possible to edit the attribute table within the command console in GRASS?

Could I do it in the same bash script which I use to do all the other processes in GRASS?

I've been reading [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102001/how-to-use-python-to-set-a-variable-to-a-value-from-a-vector-attribute-table-for) but I'm not sure how to apply it to my problem. I couldn't find how to calculate the polygons area and add it to a new column using GRASS.
I think I could use `db.select` to search for the polygons I want to eliminate, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If your products are classification rasters, you can parse [r.report](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass63/manuals/r.report.html) and [r.describe](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass63/manuals/r.describe.html) to obtain the desired results. No need to create a vector

Comment: Thanks nickves, I've been `r.report` and `r.describe`, both very useful but, in this case, I need to do some edition to the vector after the whole process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can do that using ogr2ogr, after exporting vectors from GRASS to shp:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM file_in WHERE 'category' == 2 AND OGR_GEOM_AREA > 10000" file_out.shp file_in.shp
```

file_in.shp is your data exported from GRASS

file_out.shp is your filtered results.

Then you can run:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT count(OGR_GEOM_AREA) FROM file_out" file_out.shp
```

Or if you don't need filtered results, just place WHERE argument:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT count(OGR_GEOM_AREA) FROM file_in WHERE 'category' == 2 AND OGR_GEOM_AREA > 10000" file_in.shp
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks jzol! I didn't know `ogr2ogr` and is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Lucas please upvote helpful answers and accept the answer which solves your problem. That way, the system automatically marks your question as answered